# ERROR Google Cloud SQL query syntax with Cloud Shell

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I cannot understand the syntax error :

My queries in the Cloud Shell (GCP):

```
CREATE TABLE contacts (name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255), id SERIAL);
INSERT INTO contacts (name, email) VALUES ('test', 'test@email');
SELECT * From contacts;
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

the syntax seems about right. However, it keeps failing.
Can someone points me to the documentation to find out what's correct ? I cannot locate it anywhere

Comment: Did you select the database first (use contacts;)? I do not see anything wrong with your SQL statements. Edit your question with more details showing how you are using the **client** to connect to Cloud SQL.

Comment: I had not ! my bad

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @JohnHanley, you have to select your database first before performing any SQL statements.

Sample output:
[image]

For more information, refer to this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-instance-cloud-shell) guide.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction